# how to transfer text link on an image to a clickable link?

Tags: image, text, hyperlink

I want to transform a text link to a clickable link on an image, could you please provide some suggestion? the whole process should be done in a web based application. is there any open source framework doing this?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to make a label  clickable? If so you can use javascript for that

Like

< label id="LblId"  class="StyleToLabel"  onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'"  onclick="JavascriptFunctionName('Parameter')" >Click Here< /label>

Hope it helps